# How to only show certain words in a query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

In my test program, users can save playlists, and they can call them whatever they want. For example, if user `James Smith` saves a playlist called `My Playlist` the name of the table would be `James Smith_My Playlist`. How would I go about making it so when they want to search all **their** playlists, it **only** shows the playlists starting with `James Smith_` BUT NOT show their name or the underscore in the output.

My intended result:

- User saves playlist
- Playlist is called `FirstName LastName_NameOfPlaylist`
- User selects "View all playlist [tables]"
- The output *only* displays tables starting with `FirstName LastName_` BUT DOES NOT show that in the output, only `NameOfPlaylist`

I know how to query tables begining with certain letters/words, I just cannot figure out how to output it, without the `FirstName LastName_`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a single table, `playlists`, with a field called `playlist_name`? The whole point of of a database is to be able to query data and filter by specific parameters, not divide data into an indefinite number of tables.

Comment: In addition to `playlist_name` you'd also have `user_first_name` and `user_surname`. Or have just `username` since names might not conveniently work with Western conventions. But still, the principle is to have a single table with fields that allow you to differentiate between playlists.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to set up databases; you don't define an indefinite number of tables, all holding similar information, for the purposes of getting specific results back. Instead, you should put all of your playlist data into a single table, but provide enough fields with which to differentiate what values are returned from your queries. An example (simplified, it's not a complete solution!):

```
import sqlite3

def create_database():

    with sqlite3.connect('all_playlists.db') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("DROP TABLE playlists") # Gets messy if you re-run the code otherwise

        c.execute("""
                  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists(
                      playlist_name TEXT,
                      username TEXT,
                      song_title TEXT)
                  """)


def add_playlist(playlist_name, username, songs):
    with sqlite3.connect('all_playlists.db') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        for song in songs:
            c.execute("""
                      INSERT INTO playlists VALUES (?, ?, ?)
                      """, (playlist_name, username, song))


def get_all_playlists(username):
    with sqlite3.connect('all_playlists.db') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""
                  SELECT DISTINCT playlist_name
                  FROM playlists
                  WHERE username = ?
                  """, (username,))
        return c.fetchall()


def get_songs_in_playlist(playlist, username):
    with sqlite3.connect('all_playlists.db') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""
                  SELECT song_title
                  FROM playlists
                  WHERE playlist_name = ?
                  AND username = ?
                  """, (playlist, username))
        return c.fetchall()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_database()
    # Add some users and songs
    add_playlist('happy times', 'John Smith', ['Song A', 'Song B'])
    add_playlist('sad times', 'John Smith', ['Song C', 'Song D'])
    add_playlist('something else', 'John Smith', ['Song E', 'Song F', 
                                                  'Song G'])
    add_playlist('running out of ideas', 'Janet', ['Song F', 'Song G', 
                                                  'Song H'])

    # Get playlists of John Smith
    print("John Smith's playlists are: ", get_all_playlists('John Smith'))

    # Get Janet's
    print("Janet's playlists are: ", get_all_playlists('Janet'))

    # Get all songs in happy times
    print("All songs in happy times playlist by John are: ",
          get_songs_in_playlist('happy times', 'John Smith'))
```

You also shouldn't rely on identifying users by name alone if your application gets sufficiently large since you'll get name collisions. In such cases you'd need a login system that maps a user to a userid and then you can use that for joining tables.